# Initialize and print const char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I got this code:

```
const char *newLine = "\n";
printf('Content: %c\n', *newLine);
```

What happens now is a memory error.

Why is that happening?

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Single quotes are for characters, use double quotes for strings.

Comment: what do you mean by memory error ? show us the error if possible.

Comment: Strings are surrounded by double quotes. Change `'Content: %c\n'` to `"Content: %c\n"`.

Comment: The weird thing is that the single quoted string turns into a character, an integral type, then into a pointer and printf happily takes that pointer and tries to dereference it. But won't the C compiler give a warning in this case, attempting to pass an int into a char* pointer?

Comment: @cadaniluk: Actually, it compiles -- but, of course, doesn't do what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code crashes with a memory error (segmentation fault) because `printf` expects a null-terminated string as the first argument (i.e. a valid address pointing to some characters ending in a zero byte), but you are passing an (effectively random) integer to it which is not a valid address (unless you are very, very lucky :-).

As people commented, use double quotes to pass an actual string allocated by the compiler somewhere:

```
const char *newLine = "\n";
printf("Content: %c\n", *newLine);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
const char* newLine = "new Line";
printf("Content: %s\n", newLine);
```